# Finding difference between two dates code not working in Firefox (version 40.0.3)

Tags: javascript, datetime, firefox

Recently moved our system from Chrome to Firefox and all code has worked fine except this one:

(I am fairly new to coding so I apologies if code looks dreadful but I had to convert from EU dates to US date so I could parse them to get a time difference.)

```
var start = Browser.getValue(getElement("mystarttime"));
var eu_date1 = start;
var parts = eu_date1.split('.');
var us_date1 = parts[1]+'-'+parts[0]+'-'+parts[2];

var end = Browser.getValue(getElement("myendtime"));
var eu_date2 = end;
var parts = eu_date2.split('.');
var us_date2 = parts[1]+'-'+parts[0]+'-'+parts[2];

if (start && end){
    var diff = Date.parse(us_date2) - Date.parse(us_date1);
    var timediff = msToTime(diff); /* Call function 1 */
    Browser.setValue(getElement("totaltimeholder"), timediff);
}
else if (start && !end){
    var end = new Date();
    var diff = Date.parse(end) - Date.parse(us_date1);
    var timediff = msToTime(diff);
    Browser.setValue(getElement("totaltimeholder"), timediff);
}
```

It calls this function:

```
function msToTime(duration) { /* Call function 1 */
    var d, h, m, s;
    s = Math.floor(duration / 1000);
    m = Math.floor(s / 60);
    s = s % 60;
    h = Math.floor(m / 60);
    m = m % 60;
    d = Math.floor(h / 24);
    h = h % 24;

    d = (d < 10) ? "0" + d : d;
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    return d + ":" + h + ":" +  m;
}
```

It return `NaN:NaN:NaN`. Have looked on this site and cannot find information on what could have gone wrong. This works perfect in IE also.

Comment: Probably not directly related to your problem, but in your `else if` branch, you create end as a `new Date();` and subsequently call `Date.parse(end);` This looks wrong - end is already a Date, so you don't have to parse it.

Comment: firefox wont parse a date in the format 11-9-2015

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda... FF only works with / and not -. Luckily Chrome and IE works on this format too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `msToTime()` function works fine in Firefox, too. That having said, you must be providing a wrong value into that function which is not a number.

The problem must lay in your code above. Unless you show us what `start` and `end` value is, it's hard to figure out where the real problem is.

Just start debugging with `console.log(diff)` and look what the value is. And then go up and check which value causes the problem.

Comment: Start and End and the eu and us dates are showing as expected. Something is wrong with Diff.. Will have to see if Date.parse works. Thank you for the tip

Comment: Here is the 4 values:              eu_date1: 13.01.2015 12:00
eu_date2: 21.09.2015 07:39
us_date1: 01-13-2015 12:00
us_date2: 09-21-2015 07:39       When I use Date.parse, it returns NaN in firefox but returns 01:20:30 in all other browsers

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Could you solve it? The thing is, that it's an invalid date format. Chrome maybe has a more fuzzy logic. You shouldn't rely on that format. What you can do is to convert it first into a proper format. You could do it like this:
`date = us_date1.replace("-", "/", "g") + " GMT";`. This will convert `01-13-2015 12:00` to `01/13/2015 12:00 GMT`. Then you can parse your date: `Date.parse(date)`.
You can read more about Date format here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Yes.. solved it thank you.. changed the - to / and it works in all browsers